# Looping transfer SSH keys while opening SSH access of my VM

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I was able to connect to my VM correctly before. I closed the SSH window and reconnected, it now just loop between "transferring SSH keys to VM" and "connecting to SSH".
This is in the console:

```sh
[19864.873131] google_accounts_daemon[720]: Adding user gurvanbk to group google-sudoers
Mar 26 19:07:01 winter-lounge google_accounts_daemon[720]: Adding user gurvanbk to group google-sudoers
Mar 26 19:07:41 winter-lounge google-accounts: INFO Adding user gurvanbk to the Google sudoers group.
```

It keeps looping that log.
Also here is [another post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1008648/looping-transfer-ssh-keys-while-opening-ssh-access-of-my-vm) I made on ServerFault.

nmap result:

```sh
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nmap XX.XX.XXX.XXX
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-28 12:48 Paris, Madrid
Nmap scan report for 245.151.90.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.90.151.245)
Host is up (0.027s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.17 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

That log of google_accounts_daemon on the serial console is not an ssh or sudoer issue, it looks more like a network one. Following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh):

- So we manage to see this port is open. Now verify again GCP firewall rules (gcloud compute firewall-rules list), if you don't see 22 fw rule you can create it (gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22).
- Then if all network setup it's ok, try to delete all SSH keys from VM instance metadata and from Compute engine metadata and stop and start your VM Instance, this will force google to create new ssh keys and push them to the vm instance, finally try to connect again.
- If this last method don't work, delete again all ssh keys from Compute Engine metadata and VM instance metadata. Then enable [OS login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin) feature to try other method of ssh keys injection to your VM instance, once it is activated, stop and start the instance and try to connect again.

Comment: Hi, I also asked on Server Fault, with more details. I tried to remove metadata of VM and Compute engine, but that still doesn't work. You can check my post on server fault if you want more infos. I already verified port 22 and GCP rules, they are good. Also if I use google cloud shell, and connects with a new user to the instance, I access all my files and can run them (python files). I also tried to connect to the serial console, but I don't know why to do from here. Could you tell me?

Comment: Hello, share to me the link to your other post to take a look at it.

Comment: Oh, yeah [here is the other post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1008648/looping-transfer-ssh-keys-while-opening-ssh-access-of-my-vm)

Comment: Ok, I already read it, please run < nmap external_IP > command from any console you have and share to me the output.

Comment: I don't have any console with nmap installed, is there an easy way to install it?

Comment: The nmap can be done from any computer wirth internet access, take a look at this tuitorial for a linux OS that explains also how to install it :https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-nmap-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks, I'm on windows so I found it by myself, here's the result:


```PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nmap 34.90.151.245
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-28 12:48 Paris, Madrid
Nmap scan report for 245.151.90.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.90.151.245)
Host is up (0.027s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.17 seconds
```